# Adjectives to describe a world where things are overvalued and overrated?

Tags: phrase-requests

Are there any particular colloquial expressions to describe a world where things are overrated and overvalued?

For example,

> A company publishes a four-page document and calls it an Ebook.  We live in a _____

Comment: *bubbly*?.......

Comment: Sounds good @Drew

Comment: What do you mean when you say "a world?"  Is this a hypothetical alternate universe?  If so, you might want to post on https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I want to say that we live in a world where things are getting overrated and overvalued. For example, a company publishes a 4 pages doc and calls it an Ebook.

Comment: @Drew "Bubbly"? I take it you mean the real thing, Champagne. Sparkling wine doesn't do it for me. Mine's a pint of Krug, squire.

Comment: hyper-topia ? (hyperbole + world ending) hypeberboltopia ? or as a phase.. perhaps 'a hyperbolic world' .. Hyperbole can also be used in the negative sense, but I believe the default is to assume "over hyped" not "over-disparaged"

Comment: @PeterPoint: No; see inflationary bubble. Just a joke.

Comment: "Trumpian world".

Comment: A world of exaggeration, partly due to affluence and the competition for the consumer's funds.

Comment: @Drew My most profound apologies. As someone who has recently fallen off the wagon and resumed consuming pints of Krug, I evidently missed the bubble. I promise to do better next time...hic!

Comment: *inflationary*....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A phrase which has a broader meaning but may still work is "***fool's paradise***".

> A company publishes a four-page document and calls it an Ebook. We
>   live in a ***fool's paradise***.

M-W:

> **[fool's paradise](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fool%27s%20paradise)**
>   *noun*
>   [Definition of fool's paradise for English Language Learners]
>   : a state of happiness that is based on mistaken beliefs or false
>   ideas